# Positive column in the character table of finite groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

By going through the character table of small finite groups [here](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/characters.html), we can observe that there always have a single column where all the entries are positive numbers (i.e. the one giving the dimension of the irreducible complex representations).

**Question**: Is it true in general that there is always a single such column?

*Bonus question*: What if we replace positive by non-negative?

Comment: That column is given by evaluating a character at the identity element, which is the trace of the identity operator on the representation, which is the dimension of the representation. Since every group has an identity, that column always exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (for both questions) because the columns are orthogonal.